# How to update values in row based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set as below, and trying to update hike percent based on the previous and current salary for an employee based on certain conditions, as for hike_percentage column some values aren't correctly updated instead given as 0.Hence below conditions used to correct the hike_percentage column values

```
df

Employee  Previous_ctc Current_ctc Hike_perecentage
1         5000         10000       100
2         15000       20000         0
3         16000       18000         0
4         20000       20000         0
```

Conditions:
Considering hike percent==0 rows
Considering the current CTC not equal to 0
Considering current ctc doesn't match previous ctc
Finally performing computation i.e. (ctc- previous ctc)/previous ctc)*100 - to get the percentage increase.

We see that in the above dataset , for employee 2, 3 the hike_percentage values are incorrect ,
hence by using the above conditions  we get only the employee 2,3 rows only where the ouput should be as below

```
Expected output:

Employee  Previous_ctc Current_ctc Hike_perecentage
1         5000         10000       100
2         15000       20000        33.3
3         16000       18000        12.5
4         20000       20000         0
```

I have tried multiple approaches suggested however its throwing error .One of the tried below code and is throwing error and isn't updating as expected output.

```
Code:

    df['Appraisal Percent'] = df['Current_ctc'].apply(lambda x:round((x['Current_ctc']- 
    x['Previous_ctc'])/x['Previous_ctc'])*100,decimals=1 if x!=0 elif x['Final Fixed 
    Compensation']!=x['Previous_ctc'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Hike_perecentage'] = df['Hike_perecentage'].mask(df['Hike_perecentage'].eq(0), df['Current_ctc'].sub(df['Previous_ctc']).div(df['Previous_ctc']))
```

Optionally with [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

```
df['Hike_perecentage'] = df['Hike_perecentage'].mask(df['Hike_perecentage'].eq(0), df.eval('(Current_ctc-Previous_ctc)/Previous_ctc'))
```

Output:

```
   Employee  Previous_ctc  Current_ctc  Hike_perecentage
0         1          5000        10000        100.000000
1         2         15000        20000          0.333333
2         3         16000        18000          0.125000
3         4         20000        20000          0.000000
```

Comment: Thankyou for the quick response. However using this where are we mentioning the conditions? first hike percent==0  then 
 current CTC not equal to 0 , finally current_ctc != previous_ctc : once these conditions are satisfied for these rows only the calculation to be done

Comment: `df['Hike_perecentage'].eq(0)` is the condition for Hike_percentage to be null, you can include other conditions although they are currently unclear. Can you provide a more complex input?

Comment: the other conditions are Current_ctc should be 0 and also the Current_ctc and previous_ctc  should be not equal .

Comment: Can you update your example to reflect this?